# bigquery decorator absolute time interval inclusive or exclusive

Tags: google-bigquery

So I am using bigquery decorator to query a time interval using absolute timestamp as say the example shown in their documentation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [data-sensing-lab:gartner.seattle@<time1>-<time2>]
```

I just want to confirm is `time1` and `time2` inclusive and exlusive. Am I query `[time1, time2]` or `(time1, time2)` or `(time1, time2]` or `[time1, time2)`

I arbitrarily assume it is `[time1, time2)` but I still want to double check

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to confirm is time1 and time2 inclusive and exclusive?

It is inclusive!

Comment: so you both is inclusive?

Comment: both are inclusive and btw both are milliseconds since the epoch